# Multiple object detection and tracking with tensorflow

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api

I'm working on multiple object tracking. Basically, I want to use the detections from the TensorFlow object detection API and feed it to a CRST tracker.
I managed to extract the coordinates of the detected objects, but I don't know how to feed them to the tracker because every detection will be assigned to a new tracker, resulting in many trackers on the same object. Does anyone know what's the best way to approach this?

Comment: What do you mean by "many trackers on the same object"?

Comment: I apologies I meant bounding boxes

Comment: If your problem is that, each of the objects in the image has a lot of bounding boxes assigned to them with different confidences, you could use [Non-maximal Suppression](https://www.coursera.org/lecture/convolutional-neural-networks/non-max-suppression-dvrjH) to remove similar detections with lesser confidence.